# Controlar Excepción, discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound

Tags: python, discord.py

Tengo varios BOTS corriendo, sus comandos se ejecutan mediante `!loquesea`, están en scripts diferentes, la cosa es que cuando se ejecuta un comando de uno por ejemplo `!call`, en el script de otro BOT distinto se detecta esta llamada y claro salta la excepción porque en ese BOT no esta implementada esa función, quiero de alguna manera poder manejar la excepción y que no salte.

He intentado poner un bloque `TRY...CATCH`, pero no me deja:

[image: Ejemplo]

Comment: Y cual es el codigo? Por que dices que no funciona?

Comment: @Christian si funciona, solo que quiero que no salte esa excepción

Comment: Usa un `try/except`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes conseguir eso redefiniendo el evento [`on_command_error()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=on_command_error#discord.discord.ext.commands.on_command_error), que es el manejador de errores al que se llama cada vez que ocurre un error de la familia [`CommandError`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=on_command_error#discord.ext.commands.CommandError).

Si el error es una instancia de [`CommandNotFound`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=on_command_error#discord.ext.commands.CommandNotFound), entonces ignora el error. Si no lo es, vuelve a lanzar el error que se produjo mediante la "keyword" `raise`:

```
from discord.ext import commands

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx : commands.Context, error : commands.CommandError):

    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        return

    raise error
```